# Parsing files used in creation of eval.tfrecord

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am trying to obtain the .jpg files used to create the eval.tfrecord.

I am having trouble just opening the file using python and running a regular expression on the file to find all .jpg files listed randomly throughout the file.

Now I have the file open using the below code and see one of the .jpg files I need in a structured form:

```
  feature {
    key: "image/source_id"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value: "path/to/image.jpg"
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the code to get the above result:

```
#From the Tensorflow Docs:

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

import numpy as np
import IPython.display as display

record_iterator = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator("eval.tfrecord")

for string_record in record_iterator:
  example = tf.train.Example()
  example.ParseFromString(string_record)

  print(example)

  # Exit after 1 iteration as this is purely demonstrative.
  break
```

I would like to just get the .jpgs used and not all the data in the file. Maybe there is someway I can specify the feature with key: image/source_id to get all .jpgs used in the creation of the tfrecord?

Answer (score 0):

I redirected the output of "print(example)" into a file. Then was able to read in that file and parse it as normal using regex to look for .jpg files.